# How to use python to batch hexadecimal

Tags: python

StackOverFlow
I have a question. Enter two numbers, one is a 'D1', and the other is a 'D2' they are all hexadecimal, 'D2' such as: [6e], then use the 'D2' to subtract each number in hexadecimal such as: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7 to F6,F7,F8,F9,FA,FB,FC,FD,FE,FF), assign the subtracted value to a new variable, then use the new variable to XOR the 'D1','D1' such as [d0], and output the result of the XOR. I simply wrote a bunch of codes

```
r = input("D2: ")
k = input("Hex: ")
o = int(r, 16)
l = int(k, 16)
d = o - l
s = input("D1: ")
e = int(s,16)
y = d ^ e
print(hex(y))
```

[Program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UQm4.png)

[The general flow of calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F0Io.png)

[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsDK8.png)

Can tell me how to perform batch operations with hexadecimal..

Comment: You said you had a question, but didn't post one. What is the question?

Comment: I think it's this(Po7mn1 has edited the question) -> Can tell me how to perform batch operations with hexadecimal..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear to me, but I'll try to give you some pointers so that you can figure the rest out yourself.

`hex()` does not operate on lists, dicts, or any types of data besides integers. Usage is `hex(5)` and it will return the hexadecimal representation of this integer as a `str`.

This means you will have to implement any sort of 'batch operation' yourself. You can use for-loops and lists, like so:

```py
nums = [42, 1, 99]
hex_nums = []
for num in nums:
    hex_nums.append(hex(num))
```

A shorter way to do the same thing is to use a list comprehension:

```py
nums = [42, 1, 99]
hex_nums = [hex(num) for num in nums]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I mean I want to subtract each hexadecimal number through D2 and print it on the screen, and then use the value printed out by D1 XOR D2. I drew a picture so maybe you can understand :D [Picture][3] [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsDK8.png